# Which Hal Clement books are in the same universe as 'Mission of Gravity'?

Tags: hal-clement

Obviously *Star Light* is a sequel to *Mission of Gravity*, and the other Mesklin stories "Under" and "Lecture Demonstration" are directly related.

I noticed, though, a while back that *Star Light* is connected to *Close to Critical* -- Easy refers to "when a concatenation of errors had stranded her in an unmanned research vessel on a high-temperature, high-pressure planet", and there are a couple of references to Drommians as well.

Are any other of Clement's books connected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Officially there are no other books in the *Mesklin* universe; it is highly likely that there aren't any other short stories either.  The [SF Encyclopedia entry for Hal Clement](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/clement_hal) says this about his *Mesklin* series:

> Clement's most famous – and far better – work is contained in his main series, the loose **Mesklin** sequence consisting of *Mission of Gravity* (April-July 1953 Astounding; cut **1954**; text restored with additions and one added story, as coll **1978**), *Close to Critical* (May-July 1958 Astounding; **1964**) and *Star Light* (June-September 1970 Analog; **1971**); [...] *Star Light* is a direct sequel to the first, while some of the characters in the second appear in the third as well, Elise ("Easy") Rich in *Close to Critical* being the "Easy" Hoffman of *Star Light*, 25 years older. *Mission of Gravity*, one of the best-loved novels in sf, is set on the intriguingly plausible high-gravity planet of Mesklin [...]

Note that the Science Fiction Encyclopedia does not normally list individual short stories unless they are of particular note, so "Lecture Demonstration" and "Under" aren't mentioned here.

The [ISFDb entry for the *Mesklin* series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?573) lists *Mission of Gravity* (1954), *Close to Critical* (1964), *Star Light* (1971) as well as "Lecture Demonstration" (1973) and "Under" (2000) along with a number of translations and omnibuses that don't count as additional works.

A lot of his short fiction I haven't read, but of the novels on his [main ISFDb page](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?233), I'm familiar enough with *Iceworld*, *Cycle of Fire*, *Ocean on Top* and *The Nitrogen Fix* to say they're definitely not directly associated with the *Mesklin* series.  (In a world where Asimov can retcon the *Foundation* series into the same universe as the Elijah Baley novels, there's nothing to say that, for example, *Cycle of Fire* **couldn't** be put in the same universe as *Mesklin*, but *as yet* there's nothing connecting them.)

Comment: OK, thanks! It didn't occur to me that the series itself would have an ISFDB entry that would answer the question, I'm still relatively unfamiliar with using ISFDB.  (Cycle of Fire was what I was primarily wondering about, since the universe/background seems more similar than those other books: I wondered if I'd missed an implied connection).